# Find the distance between the centers of the circles given angle between two external tangents

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles

> Two circles have radii $15$ and $95$. If the two external tangents to the circles intersect at
> $60$ degrees, how far apart are the centers of the circles?

I have tried various different figures but none of them give me the correct answer i.e. $160$. There is no other information about how the circles are arranged.

Comment: There must be a typo in either the problem or the answer key. You should still explain how you solved it and what answer you got instead.

Comment: @dxiv I used cosine rule just like this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285714/distance-between-centers-given-angle-between-tangents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$
d=\frac{80}{\sin 30^{\circ}}=160
$$